# Ribbon controls in Delphi

Tags: delphi, licensing, delphi-2009, ribbon-control

I have used [TMS ribbon controls](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp) and ribbon controls came with Delphi 2009  in my project. I can remember the Delphi setup warned me about ribbon controls and said me to get license from Microsoft. What is the license and can I distribute this application as a commercial application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to the link provided by @splash:

Accepting that license basically means agreeing to stick to the Ribbon (Fluent Interface) guidelines as set out by Microsoft... (see link provided by splash). There are no restrictions on where / in what applications you use the Ribbon controls, or whether those applications are free, shareware, open source, closed commercial or whatever.

**Update**

As @The_Fox rightly mentions, there **is** a restriction to the type of application: you cannot use the Ribbon Controls in any application that **competes** with one of the Microsoft Office products.

Comment: There are restriction on what programs may use those UI guidelines: it is prohibited to use this UI in applications that directly compete with Microsoft Office products that use this UI.

Comment: @The_Fox: yes, you're right, I forgot about that one (must have blocked it from memory)

Answer (score 5):

You can only use the *"2007 Microsoft Office User Interface"* (Ribbon Controls) if you license the Office UI.

> For software vendors who wish to
>   incorporate the 2007 Microsoft Office
>   User Interface into their own products
>   or for component vendors who wish to
>   build Office UI components for use by
>   other software vendors, we are
>   offering a **royalty-free license** to use
>   the Office UI subject to very few
>   restrictions.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/officeui

Answer (score 3):

Please also make sure you adhere to the Ribbon design guidelines, Microsoft take this very seriously, plus the guidelines are quite a good standard to follow when designing your ribbon. You can view the guidelines here: http://officeblogs.net/UI/Preview%202007%20Microsoft%20Office%20System%20UI%20Design%20Guidelines.pdf

> Your Licensed UI must comply with the
>   Design Guidelines. If Microsoft
>   notifies you that the Design
>   Guidelines have been updated or that
>   you are not complying with the Design
>   Guidelines, you will make the
>   necessary changes to comply as soon as
>   you reasonably can, but no later than
>   your next product release that is 6
>   months or more from the date you
>   receive notice.